# nested row col grid view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create grid view, where row1 contains 10% height of the page and row2 90%.

I have tried to adjust this, bud body part does not grow in row2, as element of col2 in row2 increases.

Is there any good way to organize this?

Row2 has two col, col1 is body part `col-xs-8` and col2 is element selection box of `col-xs-8`

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q18yzkoz/2/

this col2 will be divided into grid of `12X2` grid.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
            <div class="header">Heeader</div>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">ad</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
            <!-- 12 repeated rows as velow -->
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">Item1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">item2</div>
                </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

seem like you have to give `<div class="element-box">` to your ad div too